# Generate Antlr4 Lexer from Java

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I know, most people let Antlr generate from the command-line, but I would like to call it from Java. I also cannot call the `main` of the Tool class, since this class uses `System.exit`, since this exits my program as well.

What I tried so far is the following:

```
        String g4Content = "My Grammar Content";            

        String[] arg0 = {pathOfG4File, "-package", "mypackage"};

        Tool tool = new Tool(arg0);

        GrammarRootAST ast = tool.parseGrammarFromString(g4Content)
        Grammar grammar = tool.createGrammar(ast);

        tool.process(grammar, true)
```

I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.antlr.v4.parse.BlockSetTransformer.inContext(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
at org.antlr.v4.parse.BlockSetTransformer.setAlt(BlockSetTransformer.java:467)
at org.antlr.v4.parse.BlockSetTransformer.topdown(BlockSetTransformer.java:370)
at org.antlr.v4.parse.BlockSetTransformer.topdown(BlockSetTransformer.java:24)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeRewriter$2.rule(TreeRewriter.java:108)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeRewriter.applyOnce(TreeRewriter.java:61)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeRewriter$1.pre(TreeRewriter.java:92)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:28)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:33)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:33)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:33)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeVisitor.visit(TreeVisitor.java:33)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeRewriter.downup(TreeRewriter.java:95)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.TreeRewriter.downup(TreeRewriter.java:86)
at org.antlr.v4.tool.GrammarTransformPipeline.reduceBlocksToSets(GrammarTransformPipeline.java:89)
at org.antlr.v4.tool.GrammarTransformPipeline.process(GrammarTransformPipeline.java:78)
at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:360)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1080)
at de.ustutt.sidewise.editor.generator.BnfModelGenerator.doGenerate(BnfModelGenerator.java:53)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.handleChangedContents(BuilderParticipant.java:524)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.handleChangedContents(BuilderParticipant.java:513)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.doGenerate(BuilderParticipant.java:498)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.doBuild(BuilderParticipant.java:263)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant.build(BuilderParticipant.java:221)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant$DeferredBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:161)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.RegistryBuilderParticipant.build(RegistryBuilderParticipant.java:69)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.doBuild(XtextBuilder.java:252)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.fullBuild(XtextBuilder.java:280)
at org.eclipse.xtext.builder.impl.XtextBuilder.build(XtextBuilder.java:117)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest to build your Parser / Lexer in your build process with Maven or a similar build tool

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks for your comment, but that is not possible for me. I dynamically generate the .g4 file and have to generate the Lexer from that file.

Comment: that's still ok. Either you generate the grammar earlier in the lifecycle or in a separate project

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Well I need to do it during the runtime. I am not sure, but using Maven or Ant on during runtime, seems wrong to me. Isn't there another solution?

Comment: No you're right, it seems wrong to me also. But so does generating a Lexer at runtime :-(

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Depends on the Use Case ;) In my case it makes sense (at least to me and my colleagues ;))

Comment: But do you do it repeatedly? How do you unload the previous lexer and load the next one?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd We are writing an Eclipse Plugin. A user writes a grammar and wants the Lexer to be generated. At a given Point in Time he or she may want to lex some input. Thats the baseline of our project. We don't care about the generated Lexer at runtime, we just create it. The user has to wrap his or her business logic around that Lexer and executes everything when finished.

Comment: ah ok. in that use case, it might make sense

Comment: This looks like a problem with the class loader. Look at the calling method `setAlt()`. It is found in the maven artifact `antlr4` while the called method `inContext` is part of the maven artifact `antlr4-runtime`. If you use maven `antlr4` should contain `antlr4-runtime` but if you use jar-files, you might have missed the `runtime.jar` - or you have different versions in caller and callee.

Comment: Couldn't you just spawn a child Java process to run the ANTLR tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known working implementation:

```
private void compileGrammar(IResource resource, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    if (resource != null && resource instanceof IFile && (resource.getName().endsWith(".g4"))) {
        IFile file = (IFile) resource;

        try {
            String outputDirectory = determineBuildFolder(file).toString();
            Log.info(this, "Building  [file=" + file.getFullPath() + "]");
            Log.info(this, "Output to [dir= " + outputDirectory + "]");
            monitor.worked(1);

            Tool tool = new Tool(new String[] { "-o", outputDirectory });
            tool.removeListeners();
            ErrorListener toolErrs = new ErrorListener();
            tool.addListener(toolErrs);
            monitor.worked(1);

            // Prep and process the grammar file
            String loc = file.getLocation().toPortableString();
            Grammar g = tool.loadGrammar(loc);
            tool.process(g, true);
            monitor.worked(1);

            if (toolErrs.hasErrors()) {
                for (ANTLRMessage err : toolErrs.getErrList()) {
                    Log.error(this, err.toString());
                    AntlrDTCore.getDefault().showConsoleMessage(err.toString(), AntlrDTCore.MSG_ERROR);
                }
            }
            if (toolErrs.hasWarnings()) {
                for (ANTLRMessage warn : toolErrs.getWarnList()) {
                    Log.warn(this, warn.toString());
                    AntlrDTCore.getDefault().showConsoleMessage(warn.toString(), AntlrDTCore.MSG_WARNING);
                }
            }

            postCompileCleanup(file, monitor);
            monitor.worked(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error(this, "Build failed.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, looks like you are using XText - last I checked it was using a modified Antlr3 implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Essentially, this is the same code as mine above. I found my Issue, it was related to dependencies, that were somehow not correctly resolved. XText uses Antlr3 but not during runtime but when running the Worklfow and downloads it on the first run. Therefore, I don't think that relying on Xtext's Antlr in this case is not a good idea.